# Calculating range of two's complement

Tags: computer-architecture

This is a computer architecture question given in our college syllabus and i was finding difficulty in solving it.
Calculate the range of a 16-bit 2's complement number system for representing both signed and unsigned integers.
Please guide me.

Comment: @Brian - now i got this concept, yes it was pretty basic, but at that time i did not know it. The reason why i got confused was because of that 2's complement. 
what i think max in 2's complement will be 0111....(15 1's)
and least will be, 1000....(15 0's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non negative value, the most significant bit is 0 and the remaining 15 bits represent the value directly.

For a negative value, the most significant bit is 1 and the remaining 15 bits represent the absolute value minus one complemented.

Example for -1:

```
00000000 00000001 (absolute value)
00000000 00000000 (minus one)
11111111 11111111 (complemented) --> (-1 in 2's complement)
```

2's complement does not makes sense for unsigned numbers.

**For 16 bit unsigned:**

```
Min: 0x0000 --> 0
Max: 0xFFFF --> 65535
```

**For 16 bit signed:**

```
Min: 0x8000 --> -32768
Max: 0x7FFF --> 32767
```

2's complement is used because it simplifies sums at binary level.

Take these examples:

```
  00000000 00001010 (10 decimal)
 +11111111 11111001 (-7 decimal)
-------------------
1 00000000 00000011 (3 decimal) (the leftmost 1 is discarded because overflows the 16 bit sum)


  00000000 00001100 (12 decimal)
 +11111111 11101001 (-23 decimal)
-------------------
  11111111 11110101 (-11 decimal)
```

Comment: Your ranges are correct, but "A 2's complement number reserves the most significant bit for sign" would imply that 0 (16 0 bits)  is a positive number, which is IMO nonsense. It also hints that 1xx is the negative of 0xx (for any 15-bit xx), which is true for sign-magnitude but definitely not for 2's complement.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Just clarified that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also studied up at my room and figured it out. Although I have  a doubt, that in the hexadecimal representation, (like 0xFFFF) what does 0 represent? that its a positive number? can it be 1 also?

Comment: @user996851 `0x`, as far as I know, is just a prefix that means that the number is represented in hexadecimal format.

Comment: One more thing, suppose i want to load a hex constant into register r0, minimum number of steps is 1 right? if we are not supposed to use pseudo-instructions or assembler directives..
It would be MOV r0, #0xFFFF

Comment: @user996851 I don't know what architecture you are using but taking into account your last question I suppose you are using ARM. I never user ARM devices but I believe you can load a literal like that.

Comment: @user996851: You had that question (load a value in a register) closed because you showed no work from your side. There is more to it than a simple MOV.

Comment: yea, i figured it out, we can only send 8 bits in one time, so to send a 32 bit signal, we need to send it in 4 parts.. Anyways, thanks  for help everyone.. :)